# Hierarchical name component lookup failed

Tags: system-verilog

I'm trying to studying the case by referring https://verificationacademy.com/courses/systemverilog-oop-for-uvm-verification

To understand `$cast`, I've implemented as the below.

```
class A;
    int v=1;
endclass

class F extends A;
    int w=2;
endclass

class B extends A;
    int x=3;
endclass

class G extends B;
    int y=4;
endclass

class C extends B;
    int z=5;
endclass        

module test;
initial begin
    A a_h = new();
    B b_h;
    G g_h;
    C c_h;
    F f_h;
    $display(a_h.v);
    if ( $cast(c_h, a_h) )
        $display(c_h.z);
    else if ( $cast(g_h, a_h) )
        $display(g_h.y);
end
endmodule
```

But I've got just only

```
'1'
```

I think the below code doesn't work.

```
 if ( $cast(c_h, a_h) )
        $display(c_h.z);
    else if ( $cast(g_h, a_h) )
        $display(g_h.y);
```

Why does it have a Hierarchical name component lookup failed error?

If I want to cast G to A class then what am I supposed to do?

[casting picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WO0Lb.png)

I've got error message when I implemented like the below

```
module test;

B b_h = new();
G g_h = new();
C c_h = new();
F f_h = new();
A a_h = new();

initial begin

$cast(c_h, a_h);
$display(c_h.z);
$display(b_h.x);
$display(a_h.v);
```

The error messages

```
    $cast(c_h, a_h);
            |
ncsim: *E,BCLCST (./test1.sv,33|5): Invalid cast: a value with the class datatype '$unit_0x118af7fb::A' cannot be assigned to a class variable with the datatype '$unit_0x118af7fb::C'.
          5
          3
          1
```

As you can see, I've got 5, 3, 1 values but also Error message.
Would you please let me know why I get this error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to do this cast, you have to allocate the `derived` class first, then use it as the `base` class and only then you can cast, as in the following example.

```
class A;
  int a = 1;
endclass
class B extends A;
  int b = 2;
endclass

module C;
  B b_h = new(); // << allocate the derived class
  B bb_h;
  A ba_h;

  initial begin
    ba_h = b_h;  // << assign derived class to the base

    if ($cast(bb_h, ba_h)) // << now you can cast base to another variable of class B (or to one of its bases).
      $display(bb_h.b);
  end
endmodule
```

Comment: Thanks Serge, I'm trying to understand about $case purpose. and currently I'm referring https://imgur.com/a/94KOUnx this.

Comment: I thought that if I once declared like above, then I could use vary class, but it's not. would you let me know little a bit more about $cast?

Comment: If I want to use G to A class or F class to B class, What am I supposed to do?

Comment: you need to read about object oriented programming.  This is useful in polymorphic cases, when, for example, you use a function and pass a base class to it in arguments. `function abc(class A a)`. but sometimes the function needs to know about the exact class type passed to it.  So, it can use $cast. there are other usages as well.

Comment: in your case `A` and `B` can be casted to `G` and `C`, provided that you allocated `G` or `C` first.  In those cases `A` can also be casted to `B` as well as when you allocate just `B`. No cast between `F`, `G` , and `C` is possible.